# How do I find the Irreducible Representations from this Character Table?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, representation-theory

I have been wondering how you can get the irredcible representations of the Dihedral group $\mathbb{D}_{8}$ of order 8 from its [Character table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cWAr.jpg). $\mathbb{D}_{8}= \left \langle a,x : a^4=x^2=e, \, xax=a^{-1}  \right \rangle$

I have found a [website](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups) which states the irreducible representations which I am trying to find.

Now the first 4 one-dimensional representations are easy. They can just be read off from the character table. But I don't know how to find the matrices for the 5th irreducible representation (of dimension 2). The 2 dimensional matrices for the 5th irreducible representation are:

For $a^l$

$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \frac{2l\pi}{4} & -\sin \frac{2l\pi}{4} \\ 
\sin \frac{2l\pi}{4} & \cos \frac{2l\pi}{4}
\end{pmatrix}$

For $x$

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

And for $a^l x$

$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \frac{2l\pi}{4} & \sin \frac{2l\pi}{4} \\ 
\sin \frac{2l\pi}{4} & -\cos \frac{2l\pi}{4}
\end{pmatrix}$

My question is, how can I get these matrices by using the information in the character table? I am very new to group theory so this may be something which invoves a lot of work. I am interested to see how you would approach this. Also, is there a general method to adopt for doing this for higher orders, such as $\mathbb{D}_{12}$ and $\mathbb{D}_{16}$?

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned that the general problem of getting a representation from a character [appears to be far from easy](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=PdfExcerptURL&_imagekey=1-s2.0-S0021869385710253-main.pdf&_piikey=S0021869385710253&_cdi=272332&_orig=article&_zone=centerpane&_fmt=abst&_eid=1-s2.0-S0021869385710253&_user=12975512&md5=f68d13f61e2eb1d00d50185ca37580b3&ie=/excerpt.pdf)

Comment: I feared as much. I may instead change my question to: how can i find the character table for $D_{8}$. Is there a methodical way of approaching this? It is easy to deduce that $D_{8}$ has 4 1 dimensional irreducible representations and one 2 dimensional representation. But determining the character of that 2D irreducible representation is beyond me.

Comment: If you know about induced characters, then it is not hard to see that the $2$-dimensional character is the induction of a $1$-dimensional faithful character of the cyclic subgroup of order $4$, and that enables you to write calculate the corresponding representation.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got any knowledge when it comes to induced characters. I think I'm first going to try to understand how to construct the character table from first principles. Could anybody offer me assistence with this?

Comment: In this example, you have all of the characters except 1. In that case you can immediately calculate the final character from the orthogonality relations: two distinct columns of the table are mutually orthogonal.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help. Is this a special case though? How would this be done for $D_{12}$ for example. In that case there are two 2D representations.